# Copy Redshift table from S3 csv file using Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, psycopg2

What is the recommended module and syntax to programatically copy from an S3 csv file to a Redshift table?  I've been trying with the psycopg2 module, but without success (see [psycopg2 copy_expert() - how to copy in a gzipped csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41388555/psycopg2-copy-expert-how-to-copy-in-a-gzipped-csv-file)).  I've tried cur.execute(), cur.copy_expert() and cur.copy_from() - all unsuccessfully.   My experience and comments I've read lead me to conclude that psycopg2, while sufficient for python-programming a postgres DB, will not work for Redshift tables for some reason.  So what is the workaround if I want a Python script to do this copy?

Here is the COPY statement I want to run.  The source is a gzipped csv file with a pipe delimiter.  This works fine from a SQL interface like DBeaver, but I can't figure out how it would translate to Python:

```
'''COPY <destination_table> from 's3://bucket/my_source_file.csv.gz' CREDENTIALS <my credentials>  delimiter '|' IGNOREHEADER 1 ENCODING UTF8 IGNOREBLANK    LINES NULL AS 'NULL' EMPTYASNULL BLANKSASNULL gzip ACCEPTINVCHARS timeformat 'auto' dateformat 'auto' MAXERROR 100 compupdate on;'''
```

Answer (score 1):

I use ODBC using the pyODBC library successfully. Just call .execute(copy-command) and you shouldn't have an issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of examples online of connecting to Amazon Redshift from Python. For example:

- [Connect RedShift via Python's [psycopg2]](http://sobhan06k.blogspot.com.au/2014/11/reach-redshift-using-python-library.html)
- [Access your data in Amazon Redshift and PostgreSQL with Python and R](https://blog.blendo.co/access-your-data-in-amazon-redshift-and-postgresql-with-python-and-r/)
- [Copying data from S3 to AWS redshift using python and psycopg2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601704/copying-data-from-s3-to-aws-redshift-using-python-and-psycopg2)

They typically look like:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(...)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("COPY...")
conn.commit()
```